# Como utilizar 4 casas após a virgula, no Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preciso calcular a área de circunferência sendo: area = π . raio². Considerando para este problema que π = 3.14159 (é o meu n)

```
raio = float(input('insira o raio: '))
n = 3.14159
area = round (n*(raio*raio),4)

print ('A=',area)
```

Utilizei o `round` com 4 casas decimais após a vírgula, porém quando eu insiro o raio de "150.00" a resposta na tela é  = 70685.775, mas o correto é 70685.7750 (com 4 casas após vírgula).

Se, por exemplo, coloco raio como "2.00" ou "100.64" a resposta vem com as 4 casas decimais... Será que é por causa do zero na quarta casa? E como resolvo este caso?

Comment: Só atente-se a um detalhe importante: o segundo parâmetro de `round`, `ndigits`, refere-se à quantidade de dígitos de precisão, não à quantidade de dígitos após a vírgula. São coisas distintas e buscar entender isso evitará muitos problemas futuros.

Comment: Obrigado pela observação...